# Parse error while using DOM in PHP

Tags: php, dom, instagram

I am trying to get no. of followers by scraping Instagram.
Using following code:

```
<?php
    function callInstagram($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch); 

        return $result;
    } 

    $url = "https://www.instagram.com/ravij28/";
    $dom = new domDocument();  
    $dom->loadHTML($result); 
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
    $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script type'); 
    ?>
```

error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$dom' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\Trial\curl.php on line 20

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: `$result` is inside function, you can't access it, use `$dom->loadHTML(callInstagram($url)); `

Comment: the error is about $dom and even after using this its still occuring

Comment: I actually tried your code, with Thamilan's modification, and it doesn't give the error you report. After adding: `print_r($tables);` I get: `DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 ) `.

Comment: Is that exactly the same code what you are using/running?

Comment: This is probably not the whole code. You are missing semicolon or parenthesis somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

```
function callInstagram($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $result;
} 
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/ravij28/";
$dom = new domDocument();  
$dom->loadHTML(callInstagram($url)); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script'); 
print_r($tables);
```

this show DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 11 ) AND

```
 $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script type'); 
print_r($tables);
```

Show 
DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )

Comment: Showing this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\Trial\curl.php on line 10

Comment: $url = "https://www.instagram.com/ravij28/";
    $dom = new domDocument();  
    $dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url)); 
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
    $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script type'); 
 print_r($tables);

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(instagram.com/ravij28/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\Trial\curl.php on line 5
Do i need to install something to use this function: file_get_contents

Comment: instagram.com/ravij28/  add https://

Comment: do i need to use curl or not?

Comment: yes u can use curl, i get result by curl in my local,r u try ur code in online editor?

Comment: <?php  
function callInstagram($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2))
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $result;
} 
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/ravij28/";
$dom = new domDocument();  
$dom->loadHTML(callInstagram($url)); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script'); 
print_r($tables);
?>
I am getting error of unexpected $result

Comment: missing semicolon  in  "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2))"  and use url with "https://" and "www." instagram.com/ravij28/>?